# Express $(z-e^{i\theta})(z-e^{-i\theta})$ as a quadratic function with real coefficients

Tags: complex-analysis

Express $(z-e^{i\theta})(z-e^{-i\theta})$ as a quadratic function with real coefficients.

**My attempt:**

$(z-e^{i\theta})(z-e^{-i\theta}) \\ $

$=(z-(cos\theta+isin\theta))(z-(cos\theta-isin\theta)) \\ $

$=z^2-z(cos\theta-isin\theta)-z(cos(\theta)+isin\theta)+(cos\theta+isin\theta)(cos\theta-isin\theta) \\ $

$ \\ $
$Let \: a=cos\theta \: and \: b=sin\theta \\ $
$ \\ $

$\Rightarrow z^2-z(a-bi)-z(a+bi)+(a+bi)(a-bi) \\ $

$= z^2-z(a-bi)-z(a+bi)+a^2+b^2 \\ $

$= z^2-z((a-bi)+(a+bi))+1 \\ $

$= z^2-2az+1 \\ $
$\Rightarrow z^2-2zcos\theta+1$

I feel like I have some problems with arithmetic but I'm not really sure. Is this correct?

Comment: It's correct but note the following shortcut: $z^2-z(e^{i\theta}+e^{-i\theta})+1=z^2-2z\cos{\theta}+1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You answer is right, but you took kind of a long way around to the answer.

I would suggest that you hold off applying Euler's formula until later. Instead, first just do the algebra: 
$$(z-e^{i\theta})(z-e^{-i\theta}) = z^2 -(e^{i\theta} + e^{-i\theta})z + \underbrace{e^{i\theta}e^{-i\theta}}_{e^0=1} = z^2 - (e^{i\theta}+e^{-i\theta})z + 1
$$
Now bring in Euler's formula:
$$e^{i\theta} + e^{-i\theta} = (cos(\theta) + i \sin(\theta)) + (\cos(\theta) - i \sin(\theta)) = 2 \cos(\theta)
$$
Finally, substitute and you're done:
$$z^2 - 2 \cos(\theta)z + 1
$$